# Assigning Properties from one Object to Another

Tags: typescript

How can I get TypeScript to understand that the keys being provided actually belong to the target object when copying properties over from one object to another?

```
interface Example {
  value: number
  dontUpdate: string
}

const a: Example = { value: 1, dontUpdate:  'a' }
const b: Example = { value: 2, dontUpdate: 'b' }

Object.keys(b).forEach(key => {
  if (key === 'dontUpdate') return
  a[key] = b[key]
  // ^ Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Example'.
})

for (let key in b) {
  if (key === 'dontUpdate') continue
  a[key] = b[key]
  // ^ Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Example'.
}

for (let key in b) {
  if (b.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== 'dontUpdate') {
    a[key] = b[key]
    // ^ Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Example'.
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwChlkA3OPAVwgC5kRqsAjaU5AEwHtwBVHJziQGAZzBRQAc2IBfYsQS9xyOAwzZ8KALzJCFKrQYBGADRdeYAUJFkA5HDvJ5SkCpbrMuAsl37KNPTIAEzmPPyCwkF2LE7yxADyLABWEAhgAHQA1hAAnqIAFCwAlBkw3FCoiAAWBTm5vgB8ehzAMMh1eb7aunbhVpGQdsXIUBBg1FAgHHAA2vUAur7ILPN5CxwA9JvIAHpoBFgQ4MjA3sAIwGB4DdVwoqogyA4guU5guTgobAhw1KIoCDoHBjUSiYC8ZDcdofL7PcSSEBSJy-EB2MArFD-CCcZBgbinECcIF4z4oOwabwQOwZOTFBTlKAdAgY+qElYjEhkNodNk9Xr9axRYbIVxgUC0GZrXJLXSrRZbHb7VCHY4Ys74C5XG7IO4POBPF5vUlwn5-AHIIEgiBgiFPaEm8kI6Qog3ozHIbG4-GE4noR3PSlaGlyBkVZnjZBs0Aclrc9pFDJ6hIAdxAAAUoNwvlAPp1ciMAGSFqNdACEPWegsG1M5HDIc0Wy3l63ryG2ewOECOJw1eC111u90ezwNxth3zS5sBwNB4MhDon8IkLtFboxbE9AO9BNAfoDFK8wdpZHksiAA)

Comment: If you only ever expect `b` to have the keys in the interface `Example`, tell the compiler so by limiting what it thinks `Object.keys(b)` will output: `(Object.keys(b) as (keyof Example)[]).forEach(key => ...)` In the `forEach`, `key` will be `keyof Example`.

Answer (score 0):

Objects aren't guaranteed to only have the keys that you assign in the interface. Interfaces are usually a subset of keys.

Remember, TypeScript gets compiled to JavaScript. Interfaces don't exist in JavaScript. Any key on the object will get copied regardless of what your interface looks like.

That's why you are getting this error. If you want to copy specific keys over, you have to test for each one.

```
if(key === 'value') a[key] = b[key] // no error
```

Otherwise, you can just cast them as any type and understand that it won't just copy keys in your interface, but all keys on the object.

```
(a as any)[key] = (b as any)[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to make the TypeScript compiler understand that you're accessing a property of that object, you can use the keyof operator
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-extraction.html#the-keyof-type-operator

---

If you want to access the same property in two different objects, to copy one into another, you can still use the keyof operator in this way:

```js
interface Example {
  value: number;
  dontUpdate: string;
  somethingElse: boolean;
}

const a: Example = { value: 1, dontUpdate:  'a', somethingElse: true }
const b: Example = { value: 2, dontUpdate: 'b', somethingElse: false }
const copyProp = <T extends keyof Example>(source: Example, target: Example, prop: T): void => {
  target[prop] = source[prop];
}

Object.keys(a).forEach((key) => {
  if (key === 'dontUpdate'){
    return;
  }

  // Copy the property key, from object 'a' to object 'b'
  copyProp(a, b, key as keyof Example);
})

console.log(b);
```

where **extends keyof** means one of the property got from **keyof**

---

If you just want to copy an object into another, then you can use the spread operator:

```js
const copy = {
   ...source
};
```

If you want to copy an entire object, without a specific property, then you can use the spread operator with the deconstructor operator:

```js
const { dontUpdate, ...copy } = source;
```

Comment: So you basically need to do a cast no matter what?